# pg_stat_statements invalid numbers

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance

I observed two things that I cannot really explain.

1. the number of queries in pg_stat_statements are sometimes less, sometimes more than it was last time(930, 925 and then 931 within 10 seconds). Should not the number of rows increase monotonically untill it reaches 1000 (or whatever limit I set)?
2. the numbers for calls, blks_written, etc. also change nonmonotonically.

Are stats reset each day or what?